# Can a causal system generate a non-causal signal or vice versa?

Tags: signal

Can a causal system generate a non-causal signal or vice versa? I included some slides from my power point that discusses the two.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why do you consider population growth and weather forecasting as "systems", in the first place? What are their inputs and outputs and their relations?

Answer (score 1):

> Can a causal system generate a non-causal signal[?]

If a non-causal signal is input to a causal system, then the output can be a non-causal signal. However if the input is zero from \$t=-\infty\$ up to some time \$t_s\$ (\$t_s\$ being less than zero to make the input signal non-causal), then (assuming we're talking about systems that are also linear) the output of the system will also be zero up to time \$t_s\$.

In practice, the concept of a non-causal signal is not particularly useful and if I've ever heard of it before, I've had no need to remember it.

> or vice versa?

As far as I know, a signal cannot generate a system, so the answer to this is no.

Comment: I think that by "viceversa" OP means a non-causal system generating a causal signal.

Comment: @A.Darwin, in that case, if we're talking about LTI systems, and the input signal is all 0's, then the output signal will be causal whether the system is causal or non-causal. I don't think you could make a non-causal LTI system that always generates causal output signals for any input signal.